# client soap with wso2 identity server

Tags: soap, soapui

It should, through java or php or some other method, to realize what he does SoapUI, or make a request to the Identity Server and analyze the policy and use the answer to the policy to deny or allow access to the user site

Comment: Can you please paste some code ? You want do to an SOAP API ?

Comment: The purpose of my project is to manage access to a web site with two different roles, namely, administrator and user. Role management and therefore their access must be done through the policy written in XACML.

Comment: For policy writing I used the WSO2 platform in particular I used the WSO2 Identity Server. To test the validity of these policy SoapUI I used the software that generates the demand and the ability to view the answer

Comment: Take a look to : http://blog.facilelogin.com/2010/05/managing-users-and-roles-with-wso2.html (Based on Java)

Comment: Have you got time to test ?